# How to use Theme in material UI with React + Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui, next.js

I created three files shown below.

The color of `Paper` changes according to the value of `palette.type` defined in `theme.js`.

Page with palette.type: 'dark'

[image: Page with palette.type: 'dark']

Page with palette.type: 'light'

[image: Page with palette.type: 'light']

However, I don't understand how the variable `theme` works. I added two `console.log(theme)` to `index.js`. Both shows `palette.type: 'light'` regardless of the value in `theme.js`.

Result of console.log

[image: Result of console.log]

How can I pass `theme` to `index.js` (without importing theme)?

**components/Layout.js** - Shared component to apply the same layout to all pages

```
import React from 'react';
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { theme } from '../utils/theme';


class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                {this.props.children}
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
    }
}

export default Layout;
```

**pages/index.js** - One specific page

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import { makeStyles, createStyles, useTheme, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
    console.log('inside makeStyles');
    console.log(theme);
    return createStyles({
        container: {
            margin: '5px 5px 50px 5px'
        }
    })
});

export default function Index(props) {
    const classes = useStyles(props);
    const theme = useTheme();
    console.log('inside Index')
    console.log(theme);

    return(
        <Layout>
            <h2>About</h2>
            <Paper className={classes.container}>
                <p>Sample test</p>
            </Paper>
            <Paper className={classes.container}>
                <p>Sample test2</p>
            </Paper>
        </Layout>
    )
};
```

**utils/theme.js** - Separate file to write `theme`

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        type: 'dark'
    }
});
```

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue and fix it.

Comment: On your screenshot, theme is only applied to the `Paper`, however it also should change background color of the page if used correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to move `<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>` from *Layout.js* to *_app.js*.
**_app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../src/theme';

export default function MyApp(props) {
const { Component, pageProps } = props;

React.useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
        jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
}, []);

return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <Head>
        <title>My page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    </Head>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
);
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
    Component: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Theme should apply to all components and you should see `dark` in the `console.log()` print.

[Official Material-UI + Next.js example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs)

If **all** pages share the same layout you can remove `Layout` component completely.

Comment: Adding `pages/_app.js` actually works! I have one extra question. Do you have any advice about how to use `components/Layout.js` and `pages/_app.js`? They now work in a similar way. (Official page: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)

Comment: @dmjy, I've added it to the end of the answer. Having both `Layout` and `_app.js` doesn't provide any benefits unless there are several layouts in the app.

Comment: The Nextjs 13 example is now here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/material-ui-nextjs